# Load many images in vector<Mat> Opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, vector, mat

I'm trying to store multiple images in a folder on a vector  for later processing. The problem is that I get the error:

```
*Debug Assertion Failed!

Expression: vector subscript out of range.*
```

The code that I'm testing is as follows.

```
stringstream Nombre2;
vector<Mat> Imagen2;
for (int a=0; a<=Count;a++) 
{
    Nombre2.clear();
    Nombre2 << "C:\\Users\\Azu\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\Projects\\SIFT2\\SIFT2\\BBDDFaces\\"<< a+1 << ".pgm";
    imread(Nombre2.str()).copyTo(Imagen2[a]);
}
```

The images names are numerical: 1.pgm, 2.pgm, so on..

I'd appreciate, if anyone can help me fix it!

Comment: `a<Count` not `a<=Count`

Answer (score 1):

so, in your code:

```
// since Imagen2 is empty, Imagen2[a] is an access violation.
imread(Nombre2.str()).copyTo(Imagen2[a]);
```

don't overcomplicate it, just use cv::format instead of the stringstream, and do without the useless copyTo():

```
vector<Mat> images;         // another thing. use english for variable names, nothing else...
for (int a=0; a<Count;a++)  // a <=Count would do one too many...
{
    string name = format("C:\\bla\\BBDDFaces\\%d.pgm", a);
    Mat img = imread(name); // pgm implies grayscale, maybe even: imread(name,0); to return CV_8U
    if ( img.empty() )      // please, *always check* resource-loading.
    {
        cerr << "whaa " << name << " can't be loaded!" << endl;
        continue;
    }
    images.push_back(img);

    // show result:
    imshow("test",img);
    waitKey();              // yes, you need the waitKey()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But now, how can I show each vector image? Or how I can access them? 

If I do: 
`imshow ("1" images [0]);`

I visualize the first image loaded, but not with any index. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks!! I try with this modification and it works!!

Comment: so, have fun, flying opencv ;)

Comment: what's with the "use english and nothing else" :(

Answer (score 1):

im lauro reyes.
I find this form.

```
String filename = "lg.mp4";   //SOLO FUNCIONA CON VIDEOS TIPO MP4
    VideoCapture capture(filename);
    Mat frame;
    Mat imagenesT;
    vector<Mat> images;  // almacenar imagenes en la cola
    Mat converted_image;
 double dHeight = capture.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT);
 cout<< "tiene frames ___" << dHeight << endl;  
    if( !capture.isOpened() )
        throw "Error when reading steam_avi";
    capture >> frame;
    cvtColor(frame, converted_image, CV_BGR2GRAY);//2XYZ);

    for(int i=0 ;i< 584;i++ )
       {
        capture >> frame;
        if(frame.empty())
            break;
        cvtColor(frame, converted_image, CV_BGR2GRAY);//2XYZ);

        images.push_back(converted_image.clone()); //almacenar imagenes en la cola
       imshow("out", converted_image);
       imshow("in",frame);
       waitKey(20); // waits to display frame
        }  

    for(int i=0 ;i< 584;i++ )
       {    
     imshow("salida1",images[i]);
       waitKey(30);
       }
```

Comment: sorry, I probe with mp4 and avi videos